# Is there a way to add a pause/delay using pyttsx3?

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

Say I have a list of lines that I want to read off, such as:
`["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"]`

Is there a way to use the "pyttsx3" module to add a pause/delay after each line?
So, for example, it would say (which would be saved to an mp3 file):

"Line 1" *short pause** "Line 2" *short pause** "Line 3"

The engine does stop a tiny bit when I use periods and commas; however, it's not really long enough.  Also, adding multiple periods or commas to the end of the sentence doesn't work--it seems to ignore all periods/commas after the first one.

Thanks in Advance for Any Help!

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to use:

```
import time
time.sleep('However much time you want to delay')
```

In between the lines.